# Showing required error message in Controller

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hook-form

I am integrating MUI with react hook form.

I would like to display the error message with the helpertext in MUI API. But required error message takes the default html action. How can I fix this? Many thanks.

[image]

The component is as follows:

```js
          <Controller
            name="email"
            control={control}
            rules={{
              required: "Email Address is required",
              pattern: {
                value: /^\S+@\S+$/i,
                message: "Invalid email address",
              },
            }}
            defaultValue={""}
            render={({ field: { onChange, value, ...field } }) => (
              <TextField
                {...field}
                label="Email"
                fullWidth
                required
                onChange={onChange}
                value={value}
                error={Boolean(errors.email)}
                helperText={errors.email ? errors.email.message : ""}
              />
            )}
          />
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to validate via **react-hook-form** you should omit the `required` attribute. It is part of **HTML 5 form validation** which is in conflict with your custom validation.

Removing that simple attribute should do the trick:

```
  <Controller
    name="email"
    control={control}
    rules={{
      required: "Email Address is required",
      pattern: {
        value: /^\S+@\S+$/i,
        message: "Invalid email address",
      },
    }}
    defaultValue={""}
    render={({ field: { onChange, value, ...field } }) => (
      <TextField
        {...field}
        label="Email"
        fullWidth
        // required
        onChange={onChange}
        value={value}
        error={Boolean(errors.email)}
        helperText={errors.email ? errors.email.message : ""}
      />
    )}
  />
```